# How do I effectively make changes to a 3rd party django app?

Tags: python, django, pypi

I am working on a Django application which uses django-leaflet, but this question applies to any python library. I want to change some django-leaflet code to see if the changes would solve a problem we are having. What are my options? Do I need to create an example app in the django-leaflet repository and preform my modify-test loop there? Or do I need to upload individual re-named versions of django-leaflet to pypi?

Comment: If the number of changes is limited, you better perform *monkey patching*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always change the code directly in `site-packages/`, although that requires a certain level of attention to detail to prevent shooting yourself in the foot.

Other than that you can check out the code and, from the directory containing the 3rd party package's `setup.py`, do

```
pip install -e .
```

(which is similar, but better, than `python setup.py develop`)

This will install a link to the sources in `site-packages/` so you can do the modify/test loop in the 3rd party package and run tests in your own package.

The advantage being that you'll have VCS support for your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your 3rd party app by uninstalling it using `pip uninstall`, then copying (or git cloning) the app into your source tree. You may need to temporarily add a line like `sys.path.append("./django-leaflet")` to your `manage.py` file so that the 3rd party modules will be in scope.

Once you are happy with your changes, you can send them to the original author as a pull request or upload your own version of the app.